# How to set the bar chart color dynamically based on the bar value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bar-chart, singledivui

I am new to javascript and html, I am creating a student record management app for my project. Here I am using a bar chart which works fine. But I want to update the bar chart color based on the bar value.

Here my actual output:

[my student management app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqASo.png)

But here I have provided the color values directly. I want to update this based on the chart value, instead of the direct value.

Here my code is:

```js
const options = {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
        labels: ["Sub 1", "Sub 2","Sub 3","Sub 4","Sub 5","Sub 6"],
        series: {
            points: [55, 74, 25, 58, 51, 45],
            barColor: ["#449647", "#449647", "#eb6236", "#449647", "#449647", "#449647"]
        }
    },
    graphSettings: {
        yAxis: {
            startFromZero: true,
            maxTicks: 10,
            customScale: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                interval: 10
            }
        }
    }
};

const { Chart } = SingleDivUI;
new Chart('#chart-demo', options);
```

```css
body {
  padding-left: 30px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/singledivui/dist/singledivui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/singledivui/dist/singledivui.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart-demo"></div>
```

Also I updated this code in the jsFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hdfre4jn/

I used the bar chart from the below website:
https://singledivui.com/demos/bar-chart/bar-customization

Note: I already refered some other posts related to this, but I don't know how to appy those logic to this bar chart component. I tried to use those components as well, but they are little complex to me. This chart is perfectly suite my requirement, so that I am using this. Any help or leads are much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the plugin has a limited ability to perform customizations, here is how to do it:

In this situation, we need a distinct color for the smallest value, so we prepare our arrays and apply our logic, then pass them to the option json :

```
// initialize array
var points = [55, 74, 25, 58, 51, 45];
var barColor = ["#449647", "#449647", "#449647", "#449647", "#449647", "#449647"]
// get the smallest value/index
var min = Math.min(...points);
const index = points.indexOf(min);
// update the color
barColor[index] = "#eb6236";
```

```js
var points = [55, 74, 25, 58, 51, 45];
var barColor = ["#449647", "#449647", "#449647", "#449647", "#449647", "#449647"]

var min = Math.min(...points);
const index = points.indexOf(min);
barColor[index] = "#eb6236";

const options = {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
        labels: ["Sub 1", "Sub 2","Sub 3","Sub 4","Sub 5","Sub 6"],
        series: {
            points: points,
                        barColor: barColor
        }
    },
    graphSettings: {
        yAxis: {
            startFromZero: true,
            maxTicks: 10,
            customScale: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                interval: 10
            }
        }
    }
};

const { Chart } = SingleDivUI;
new Chart('#chart-demo', options);
```

```css
body {
  padding-left: 30px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/singledivui/dist/singledivui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/singledivui/dist/singledivui.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart-demo"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. limited ability means what you are saying? is it good to use this? since compare to other charts this one was very flexible to me and very light-weight. but it has low users

Comment: Some other library have functions to do that, In your case you need to do it yourself, the way I shared is good for this case